# Google Sheets. Run a script to set existing dropdowns by Index number

Tags: google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

I have a sheet with about 60 dropdown data validation controls. I would like to set groups of them to a value, based on an index number of the values in the drop down e.g.

dropdown contains values "cat", "dog, "bug", "ant", and I would like to set the value to "dog" by setting the dropdown value to index 2.

I can't find the syntax for the index, so I have used setVaue(), which works, but is not the desired method:

```
var dropdownRanges = ["dd_w", "dd_y","dd_y", "dd_z"];
  for (var i=0;i<dropdownRanges.length;i++){
      sheet.getRange(dropdownRanges[i]).setValue("Dog");
      }
```

An example dropdown is shown below. I'd like to programatically set the dropdown to display the first item (Index 1) in the list, using google script. this is to "reset" the dropdowns to a default value.

The items differ in all the dropdowns, so I must use the index, and cannot the text value.

[example dropdown in google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXTaO.png)

I feel a bit embarrassed that I can't find an equivalent to "setIndex", but then I am migrating from Excel to Google Sheets, and still haven't grasped the new ecosystem.

Comment: Please share a copy or example of your spreadsheet. Remove sensitive data if any. If possible also share a screenshot of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this is, I got the data validation options from the cell (A5 in this case), get the top option (the 0th option), and then i set the cell equal to it. this resets the cell to the top option

```
let option_0 = sheet1.getRange('A5').getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValue()

sheet1.getRange('A5').setValue(option_0);
```